USING INDEX in constraints when creating table
What is the difference when creating a table in these two ways, one of them specifying explicitly the USING INDEX clause without options?
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    ID NUMBER(19, 0) DEFAULT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT UK_MY_TABLE_CODE UNIQUE (CODE)
);

CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    ID NUMBER(19, 0) DEFAULT MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_MY_TABLE PRIMARY KEY (ID) USING INDEX,
    CONSTRAINT UK_MY_TABLE_CODE UNIQUE (CODE) USING INDEX
);

As far as I know/have seen when tried, the indexes generated will have the same name in both cases (as I am specifying the constraint name), but I wonder if there is any subtle difference or they are totally equivalent in all terms, including names, etc.
Please, notice that I'm not asking about the difference when the USING INDEX clause is present (with arguments for the clause, which is already answered) or when it is not. I'm asking about the difference between not using the clause or using it BUT WITHOUT any arguments for it, which is also possible and has apparently the same behaviour, apparently.
The DB is Oracle, by the way.
